# Cordova : cancel any upcoming vibrations

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I would like to disable vibrations on android, i'm currently using ionic.
I know it is actually not possible to disable vibrations.

But from the documentation of [cordova-plugin-vibration](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration) or [Ionic Native - Vibration](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/vibration/) :

> If passed an array of numbers, it will define a vibration pattern. **Pass 0 to stop any vibration immediately.**

So i did try something with an interval (for testing purpose) :

```
this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
  // cancel any upcoming vibration
  setInterval(function(){
    this.vibration.vibrate(0);
  }, 1); // or 50, XX, etc.
});
```

So whenever i try to call the device, the phone keep vibrating as its default behaviour.

Perhaps i didn't understand clearly the official documentation.

Anyone could clarify it for me?